# I can't see any iOS Native Module in JS

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, native-module

I have some experience with React but I'm new to React Native.
I've played around for a while, but I got stuck when I tried to write a basic native module for iOS. I've tried with both Swift and Objective C. (I have some basic experience with Swift, but Objective C is completely new for me)

Some context:

1. The project is created with `react-native-cli 2.0.1`
2. I use `XCode 9.1`

Here is the .swift class

```
import Foundation

@objc(Something)
class Something: NSObject {

  @objc
  func printSomething() -> Void {
    print("Something")
  }
}
```

Here is the bridge file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(Something, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(printSomething)

@end
```

And the Project-Brigding-Header.h

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

My App.js file

```
...
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('NativeModules: ', NativeModules);
  }
...
}
```

Here is the problem. The output of console.log() says NativeModules is an empty object:

```
2018-02-22 18:19:04.590 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] 'NativeModules', {}
2018-02-22 18:19:04.589970+0200 velimo_app_rn[14748:400982] 'NativeModules', {}
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I've read pretty much everything I could find only related to the topic but I can't see what I do wrong.
If you have any suggestion, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Only thing I can think of is perhaps somehow these files aren't being compiled. Double check that they are included in `Compile Sources` phase in Build Phases

Comment: Have you rebuilt the project? You can't just refresh using `cmd + R` if you've modified Native code.

Comment: @MattyK14 yes, many times. I’m aware of that.

Comment: @HunaidHassan thank you, I will check.

Comment: @HunaidHassan I've just checked. I can see the swift class and the bridge in `Compile Sources`

Comment: @HunaidHassan - You should have posted that as an answer, so that I can upvote the hell out of it. You just solved my half-day headbanging

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was to log the module name `console.log(NativeModules.Something)`, not the whole NativeModules object. It wasn't anything wrong with my setup.

Comment: It should have still appeared if you console logged `NativeModules`. When you did your native code, did you restart the React Native packager and re-run `react-native run-ios`?

Comment: @Dan yes, I've done it many times. I really don't get it why it doesn't show up

Answer (score 0):

If you made changes to the native iOS code, then you need to rebuild the project by
rerunning `npx react-native run-ios` and restart the server `npx react-native start`.

I also relaunched the app in the simulator.