# ReactNative NativeComponents is an empty Object

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am currently trying to import [ReactNativeHeading](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-heading) into a [Hello World Viro App for android](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/tutorial-ar) and after following [these instructions](https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-heading#android), all I get is undefined. The following code can be run in both `App.js` and `node_modules/@zsajjad/react-native-heading/ReactNativeHeading.js` with the same result:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

console.log(NativeModules) // {}
console.log(NativeModules.ReactNativeHeading) // undefined
```

The reason why I even tried to log `NativeModules.ReactNativeHeading` is because it seemed to be the solution of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48932408/i-cant-see-any-ios-native-module-in-js).

Every NativeModule I have come across tells you to insert certain lines of code into your `MainApplication.java`, which leads me to believe that the contents of the `MainApplication.java` play a role for your app. So, I tried writing jibberish into the file and expected a Syntax Error (because I thought the ReactNative CLI takes care of compiling everything) but got nothing.

My conclusion was that the ReactNative CLI does not compile the android project (or at least does not compile anything containing the `MainApplication.java`) and so I tried compiling it myself (after removing the jibberish, of course). It compiles successfully now but that still hasn't fixed my problem.

I'm really running out of ideas, especially because I have next to no experience with Java and this is my first ReactNative project. If you could give me any advice whatsoever (even if it's just something a little more specific to type into Google), I'd really appreciate it!